# Why isn't the enclosing class included in the generic parameters for inner class constructors?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {
    class Inner {
        public <T> Inner(T arg) {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Constructor<?> constructor = Test.Inner.class.getConstructors( )[0];
        System.out.println(
            "Regular parameters: " +
            Arrays.toString(constructor.getParameterTypes()) +
            "\nGeneric parameters: " +
            Arrays.toString(constructor.getGenericParameterTypes())
        );
    }
}
```

Running this prints the following.

> Regular parameters: [class Test, class java.lang.Object]
>   Generic parameters: [T]

My understanding of Java inner classes (i.e. non-static) is that their constructors implicitly have a parameter for their enclosing class. So, to get an instance of `Inner`, you call its constructor like so.

```
Test.Inner foo = new Test().new Inner(new Object());
```

And what actually happens is that the instance of `Test` is passed to the constructor for `Inner` (along with any other arguments), where it's assigned to an implicit instance field.

Examining the nullary constructor for `Inner` bears this out, as calling `getParameterTypes` returns an array containing the `Class` objects representing `Test` and `Object` (the erasure of `T`).

However, since the constructor is generic, calling `getGenericParameterTypes` instead returns an array containing only the type variable `T`. The implicit parameter for the enclosing class is missing.

This only seems to happen when the inner class constructor declares a type variable. Why does it do that? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been reported as a bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5087240

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my google fu could use some work. May I ask how you found that?

Comment: search for getGenericParameterTypes inner... the third result. The second result is this post :)

Comment: "This should be addressed in a future release.

###@###.### 2004-08-18" -- Still not addressed after 15 years.